# JCabi aspects @RetryOnFailure how to throw exception

Tags: java, aop, jcabi

I want to manually call for a retry on a method by using JCabi. Aspect oriented programming should make this easy but I can't figure it out.

```
import com.jcabi.aspects.RetryOnFailure;

public class Example
{

    public int j;

    @RetryOnFailure(attempts = 4, delay = 100, verbose = true)
    public void retryFun() throws Exception
    {
        j++;
        if(j<3)
            throw new Exception();
        else
            return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Example example = new Example();
        System.out.println(example.j);
        example.retryFun();
        System.out.println(example.j);
    }
}
```

The only example available from jcabi is this one below which doesn't show how to throw an exception to force retry call:

> Annotate your methods with @RetryOnFailure annotation and in case of
>   exception in the method its execution will be repeated a few times:
>
> ```
> public class Resource {
>   @RetryOnFailure(attempts = 2, delay = 10, verbose = false)
>   public String load(URL url) {
>     return url.openConnection().getContent();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In an exception occurs the method will retry two times, with a 10 msec
>   delay between attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, just using jcabi annotations is not enough. You should "weave" your source code or binaries. I would recommend to weave binaries, as explained here: http://aspects.jcabi.com/example-weaving.html. Add this plugin to your `pom.xml` and you're done:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>ajc</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

For those of you out there still looking for an answer, Yegor's answer is now outdated. The jcabi-maven-plugin version `0.8` he posted wasn't working for me.

After some hours of digging I have found [this](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-aspects/issues/57) which states that we should use the last version *As of this time, July 2014* is `0.9.2`.

That was my answer for why when running **mvn jcabi:ajc** I was getting errors from the link and also the weaving not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok unfortunately I found out these jcabi aspects need a custom pom.xml task to compile the required aspects in the project.

So dropping the jcabi jar inside NetBeans and compiling the above code is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives, you can add these configuration to pom.xml to weave at compilation time.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <configuration>
      <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
      <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
      <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <aspectLibraries>
          <aspectLibrary>
              <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
              <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
          </aspectLibrary>
      </aspectLibraries>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>weave-classes</id>
          <phase>process-classes</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Reference: http://aspects.jcabi.com/example-aspectj.html